# How to add points to a plot from a loop

Tags: r

OK this is driving me round the bend.

I have a data.frame `df` which gets read in from a txt file. In it I have a list of results in columns labelled per sample (called `df[1]` to `df[15]`. Each result is listed by chromosome (`df$chr`).

I would like to plot the correlation between `df[i]` and `df[15]` but organised by `chr`. Currently I am getting all the correlations plotted on a graph and plots for each chromosome are being generated. However the plots all look exactly the same so I suspect its giving me the correlation for the whole sample rather than grouped by chromosome. Can you help?

```
df <- read.delim("~/Desktop/Plots/blabl.txt", header=TRUE)
ind = unique(as.character(df$chr))
for(jj in ind) {
  for(i in 3:14) {
    indic = which(df$chr == jj)
    corrie = (cor(df[,i], df[,15]))
    points(i,corrie)
   }
  plot(i, corrie, xlim=c(0,22), ylim=c(0.7,1), pch=19, main=jj)
}
```

Comment: You're creating an indicator `indic`, but you're not using it. Try `cor(df[indic,i], df[indic,15])`instead of `cor(df[,i], df[,15])`. I cannot check it, however, as your question does not feature any example data.

Comment: OK. I managed to figure it out with this: #Get the data as display it

df <- read.delim(""~/Desktop/Plots/blabl.txt", header=TRUE)
View(df)
ind = unique(as.character(df$chr))
for(jj in ind){
  indic = which(df$chr == jj)
  plot(i, corrie, xlim=c(0,22), ylim=c(0.7,1), pch=19, type="s", main=jj)
  for(i in 5:12) {
corrie = (cor(df[,i][indic], df[,15][indic]))
points(i,corrie)
 }
}

Comment: You can post & accept your own answer to your question to both help others and get some rep!

Answer (score 0):

OK. I managed to figure it out with this: 
    #Get the data as display it df <- read.delim(""~/Desktop/Plots/blabl.txt", header=TRUE)
     View(df) ind = unique(as.character(df$chr)) 
    for(jj in ind){ indic = which(df$chr == jj) 
    plot(i, corrie, xlim=c(0,22), ylim=c(0.7,1), pch=19, type="s", main=jj) 
    for(i in 5:12) { corrie = (cor(df[,i][indic], df[,15][indic])) points(i,corrie)
     } 
       }